# OneDrive for Business for this user account cannot be retrieved, when trying access Personal Notebooks

Tags: azure-active-directory, postman, microsoft-graph-api, onenote

I am trying to Use the OneNote REST API via Postman using a tennantID, ClientId and a secret with an Access code, but I keep getting the message  "OneDrive for Business for this user account cannot be retrieved."

Now I am trying to access personal notebooks on consumer OneDrive using the url

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onenote/notebooks
```

But this should be supported according to

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/onenote-get-content and 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/onenote-api-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0#root-url

I can get the call to work using the graph explorer.

The full message is

"error": {
        "code": "30108",
        "message": "OneDrive for Business for this user account cannot be retrieved.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "2b33ec04-642e-4323-be24-eadef36df2d8",
            "date": "2019-01-23T22:10:01"
        }

Where am I going wrong?  Is there a concept I have not grasped?

Comment: I think the issue might be with the use of keyword `me` as part of the API call from Postman. Please try to use `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userPrincipalName or id}/onenote/notebooks` instead. When you use Graph Explorer, you're signed in as a user and hence using delegated permissions.. so `me` will work.. but when you're using Postman.. with clientID and client secret you're using application identity and not any specific user, so `me` would not work and hence my suggestion to use explicit `userPrincipalName` or `id` instead

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But I have tried both id and userPrincipalName, but still get the same result.

Comment: can you check if the error is any different this time? Like a permission issue or anything different than the one you originally posted? Also does this work for any user or fails for all users?